# If $X_1,\dots,X_n$ is a sample from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, can we say something about $\sum_{j=1}^n |X_i-\overline{X}|$?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value

I came across the following question earlier today:

- Let
  $
  X_{1},\ldots, X_{n}\ \mbox{be a sample chosen from}\
  X\sim N\left(\mu,\sigma^{2}\right),
  $
  that is, $X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}$ are independent and identically distributed, and
  $X_{j} \sim N\left(\mu,\sigma^{2}\right),\ \forall\ j=1,\ldots,n$.
- Let $\displaystyle\overline{X} =
  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}X_{j}$ be the sample mean, then
  $$
  \mbox{what is the expected value of}\quad 
  \frac{1}{n}
  \sum_{j = 1}^{n}\left\vert\,{X_{j} -\overline{X}}\,\right\vert\ ?
  $$.

This is an exercise problem found on a tutorial that I have. Supposedly, we need to use some sample distribution results to solve this. The trouble comes from the absolute value sign inside the sum, since $X_j$ and $\overline{X}$ are not independent in this case, we cannot say that $X_j-\overline{X}$ follows the normal distribution. Thus, I have no idea how to handle the distribution $X_j-\overline{X}$ here, and we haven't other tricks about $|X_j-\overline{X}|$. Any suggestions?

By the way, this is a tutorial for first and second year undergraduate students from non-math programs, so supposedly any advanced techniques shouldn't be required here.

**Update:** We have $X_j-\overline{X}=\frac{n-1}{n}X_j-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k\neq j}X_k$, which is a linear combination of independent normal random variables, hence is also normal. Then we can use the normal density function to find the expected value.

Comment: Note that sum of normal r.v. is normal r.v.

Comment: @openspace I got it. Thanks for your hint!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-\bracks{X_{n} - \mu}^{2}\over 2\sigma^{2}}\cdots
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-\bracks{X_{1} - \mu}^{2}\over 2\sigma^{2}}
{1 \over n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}\verts{X_{j} - \overline{X}}{\dd X_{1} \over \root{2\pi}\sigma}\cdots{\dd X_{n} \over \root{2\pi}\sigma}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-\bracks{X_{1} + \overline{X}- \mu}^{2}\over 2\sigma^{2}}
\verts{X_{1}}{\dd X_{1} \over \root{2\pi}\sigma}
\\[5mm] = & \
\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-\bracks{X_{1} + \overline{X}- \mu}^{2}\over 2\sigma^{2}}
X_{1}{\dd X_{1} \over \root{2\pi}\sigma} +
\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-\bracks{X_{1} - \overline{X} + \mu}^{2}\over 2\sigma^{2}}
X_{1}{\dd X_{1} \over \root{2\pi}\sigma}
\end{align}
Note that
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-\bracks{x - a}^{2}\over 2\sigma^{2}}
x{\dd x \over \root{2\pi}\sigma} =
{\sigma \over \root{2\pi}}\exp\pars{-\,{a^{2} \over \root{2\pi}}} +
{1 \over 2}\,a +
{1 \over 2}\,a\on{erf}\pars{a \over \root{2}\sigma}
$$
Therefore, the answer is given by
$$
\bbx{\color{#44f}{\root{2 \over \pi}\sigma\exp\pars{-\,{\bracks{\mu - \overline{X}}^{2} \over 2\sigma^{2}}} + \pars{\mu - \overline{X}}\on{erf}\pars{\mu - \overline{X} \over \root{2}\sigma}}}
$$